# getChildren method in Parent - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I wrote a code that display a window in `JavaFX`,
and I loaded XML file that gives me a number of Buttons that I need to create in run-time.

I used Parent as the root and I can't do `Parent.getChildren().add(...)`
as `Pane.getChildren().add(...)`

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    URL url = 
    this.getClass().getResource("/resources/UI.fxml");
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(url);
    Parent root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load(url.openStream());
    primaryStage.setTitle("N In A Row");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 800));
    m_GameController = 
    (MainController)fxmlLoader.getController();
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Try to cast it to child like ((Child) Parent.getChild()) .add(...)

Comment: please read the api doc of parent ... ;)

Comment: `getChildren()` is a `protected` method in `Parent` (the `public` method being `getChildrenUnmodifiable()`). Both `Group` and `Pane` override `getChildren()` to make it `public`.

Comment: `Parent.getChildren` is `protected` and therefore not accessible. Some subclasses make it `public` (`Group`, `Pane`), but not all of them do this (`ListView`, `TextField`, `WebView`). You need a expression of a type with a `public` `getChildren` method. Directly accessing the scene from the loading method should be avoided in most cases though, since this is the responsibility of the controller. You should add this kind of logic to `MainController`. BTW: you should use `load()` instead of `load(url.openStream())`. You don't need to provide the info twice.

Answer (score -1):

Use scene builder to add a container to your application then add the container variable in your application controller class. Now use the created container and add as much child as you want in it through the controller.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).